# autocomplete javascript in separate file with intellij

Tags: javascript, jsp, autocomplete, intellij-idea

I have a jsp page that creates javascript variables within a script tag, however these variables are not available as autocomplete options within a separate and included JavaScript file.

Is there anyway way to enable this functionality ?

Comment: I recommend submitting it as a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA and attaching a sample to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your javascript file insert the following :

```
/* global yourFirstVariable, youVariable2 */
```

This will also stop jslint detecting *variable used before it was defined* errors.

But no type info is available afaik, so I can not get autocomplete for `yourFirstVariable.myProperty`. If anyone knows how to get that functionality ...